# Why is file download not working in my Django view?

Tags: javascript, python, django, file

The view function in my Django application is designed to transcribe a file and generate a subtitle file in .srt format. It then identifies the transcript file and is expected to automatically download it. However, currently, the automatic download does not occur. The file was submitted on a different page that uses the `transcribeSubmit` view, while the `initiate_transcription` view is responsible for handling and returning the file. When I check the file type of `file_data` it returns `str` but I suspect it should return `bytes`(though I think this is only for binary files) as it does in a similar version of my code used elsehere but I'm not sure what to change. Here is my views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def transcribeSubmit(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            

            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            request.session['uploaded_file_name'] = filename
            request.session['uploaded_file_path'] = fs.path(filename)
            
            
            #transcribe_file(uploaded_file)
            #return redirect(reverse('proofreadFile'))
            return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete.html', {"form": form})
        else:
            
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

        
        
    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe.html', {"form": form})

@csrf_protect
def initiate_transcription(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        
        # get the file's name and path from the session
        file_name = request.session.get('uploaded_file_name')
        file_path = request.session.get('uploaded_file_path')
        if file_name and file_path:
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                path_string = f.name
                transcribe_file(path_string)
            
            file_extension = ('.' + (str(file_name).split('.')[-1]))
            transcript_name = file_name.replace(file_extension, '.srt')
            
            transcript_path = file_path.replace((str(file_path).split('\\')[-1]), transcript_name)
                
            file_location = transcript_path
            with open(file_location, 'r') as f:
                file_data = f.read()

            response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='text/plain')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + transcript_name + '"'
            return response
            
        else:
            #complete

    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete.html', {"form": form})

           
def transcribe_file(path):
#transcription logic
```

I used similar code on another view/page that worked but when adapted to this page it fails. Any ideas?